# <Grid> in Material UI - Items overlap to the right, when reducing the screen-size -> not using the left-side

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, material-design

```
<Card className={classes.cardLevel}>
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} align="center">
      <Paper className={classes.gridItem}>Grid Item</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} align="center">
      <Paper className={classes.gridItem}>Grid Item</Paper>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Card>
```

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  cardLevel: {
    border: "2px solid black",
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    width: "50%",
    padding: 20,
  },
  gridItem: {
    width: 200,
  },
});
```

Inside a card-component (with: 'border-box' + padding + border) there is a grid-container.
Inside the grid-container there are grid-items (with: align="center" and spacing={2}).
Inside each grid-item there is a 'paper-component' (with: width: 200px).

When I reduce the screen-width enough, both paper-components start to 'eat' their right sides 
(e.g. the spacing between the grids + the padding-right of Card).
 - Ok.

[image]

When further reducing the screen-width, the paper-components continue to overlap to their right side, while the original padding-left from the Card is still untouched.

[image]

How to accomplish that, when reducing the screen-width enough, before the paper-components start to overlap to the right, they should use 'eat' the padding-left from Card first?

Answer (score -1):

Only solution I found was overriding breakpoints in theme, so they do breakpoints earlier and don't touch each other

```
export const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      xs: 240,
      sm: 900,
      md: 1060,
      lg: 1660,
      xl: 1920,
    }
  }
});
```

Something like this.